# Multiple UITextfields Returns Null IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have got multiple textfield on a formsheet view. I want to append them when user clicks a button.  But only one of them returns the value in textfield rest of them returns null.

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textMonth;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textDay;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textYear;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textMeetingName;
```

.m

```
@synthesize textDay=_textDay;
@synthesize textMonth=_textMonth;
@synthesize textYear=_textYear;
@synthesize textMeetingName=_textMeetingName;


- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}
//this dismiss keyboard on ios
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

        [_textMonth resignFirstResponder];
        [_textDay resignFirstResponder];
        [_textYear resignFirstResponder];
        [_textMeetingName resignFirstResponder];


    return YES;
}
//submit create folder request to dropbox
- (IBAction)sendCreateFolderRequest:(id)sender{

    if ([_textMonth.text intValue]>12 ||[_textMonth.text intValue]<1 ) {
        //alertview choose a number between 1 and 12
        [self popUpAlertview:@"Please choose a month between 1 and 12"];
    }
    else if ([_textDay.text intValue]>31 || [_textDay.text intValue]<1){
        //alert view choose a number between 1 and 31
        [self popUpAlertview:@"Please choose a day between 1 and 31"];
    }
    else if ([_textYear.text intValue]<0){
        //alert view please enter a correct year
        [self popUpAlertview:@"Please enter a correct year"];
    }
    else if ([_textMeetingName.text length]<=1){
        //alert view meeting name is too short please enter a longer name
         [self popUpAlertview:@"Name is too short. Please enter a longer name"];
    }
    else{

        NSString *sendFolderName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Up2Date/%@.%@.%@.%@",_textMonth.text,textDay.text,textYear.text,textMeetingName.text];

        NSLog(@"Send folder name %@",sendFolderName);

    }

}
```

Input is `11,12,13,asdaad`
Output is `Send folder name /Up2Date/11.(null).(null).(null)`

Weird thing is my if else methods catches if field values are wrong such as 11,45,20 it pops up alert view as I expected.

So what seems to be the problem ? Maybe I should not resign them first responder all at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
NSString *sendFolderName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Up2Date/%@.%@.%@.%@",_textMonth.text,textDay.text,textYear.text,textMeetingName.text];
```

to

```
NSString *sendFolderName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Up2Date/%@.%@.%@.%@",_textMonth.text,_textDay.text,_textYear.text,_textMeetingName.text];
```

You forgot add the underscores.

Comment: You missed it because you used the underscores. Generally - just just use the `self.iVar` way of getting and setting property value anywhere except for initialisers and dealloc. That way you're free to mess about the with implementation without worrying about how they are used.